# How is image-slider progressing from one slide to another in attached code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was given the following code which progresses from one image to the next (previous or next) in a slider. It worls fine and I inderstand that specifically the function cycleitems does the progressing.  What I don't understand is the precise mechanism for moving the slide from  currentindex to (currentindex plus or minus 1).  Can you explain exactly what the statement **item.css('display','inline-block')** does?

The html and css are attached.

Thank you very much.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     var currentIndex = 0,
      items = $('.container div'),
      itemAmt = items.length;

    function cycleItems() {
      var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
      items.hide();
      item.css('display','inline-block');
    }

    var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
      currentIndex += 1;
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      cycleItems();
    }, 6000);

    $('.next').click(function() {
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex += 1;
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      cycleItems();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
      }
      cycleItems();
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
  <button class="next">></button>
  <button class="prev"><</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div><img src="Img1.jpg"/></div>
    <div><img src="Img2.jpg"/></div>
    <div><img src="Img3.jpg"/></div>
    <div><img src="Img4.jpg"/></div>
    <div><img src="Img5.jpg"/></div>
    <div><img src="Img6.jpg"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slider{
  width:400px;
  height:260px;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999;
  top:185px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}

.next {
  right: 5px;
} 

.prev {
  left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this program the actually current index is changed events triggered by pressing the buttons. The cycleItems() function does three things.

First it uses jQuery's .eq function. This function, as stated by the jQuery documentation constructs a new element from the element in the set with the selected index. In this case it is selecting the object inside of the container div with the index of current index.

On the next line of the cycleItems() function the actual list of items, the container div, is hidden so that it is not visible.

The last line of this function sets the display css attribute of the container div to "inline-block". **Inline block is a display type which acts as an inline element, following the flow of the text, but has the ability to have a width and  a height.**

As you can see from this each image is not its own element but instead the image dictated by the current index  is set to the variable, item, when the buttons are pressed triggering the cycleItems() function.

Comment: Thx ManOfPanda. I understand that the eq function gets the next image; that the hide method hides all .container div elements; that the last line sets the display css attribute of the container div to "inline-block". But what statement / line of code, whether it be JS or HTML, causes the image to be displayed? I last programmed in COBOL, so I'm probably confused by the event-driven paradigm.

Comment: @Trevor Well The <img> tag in html itself is responsible for actually rendering the image. The specific image is rendered because it is the only image tag actually there to be seen due to the rest of them being hidden in the line items.hide()

Comment: @Trevor No problem. Glad I could help.